# The exercise about the epsilon-delta definition of limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

The answer is D

But I think that the solution is $\sqrt{2}-1$ from the graph.
( Since $x^2-2x = 1$ when $x = 1,\sqrt{2}-1, \sqrt{2}+1$ )

Am I wrong?

Comment: How did you get your answer? Explaining all your steps will help other people understand where your answer came from.

Comment: Do you know how to construct an epsilon-delta proof? Here's a hint: start from the definition $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, where $f(x)$ is the function and $L$ is the limit.

Comment: Note: Proofs "from the graph" are not proofs. They are *ideas* of proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon = 1$.

$$ | x^2-2x|\leq 1 \Leftrightarrow (x^2-2x)^2\leq 1 \Leftrightarrow (x^2-2x-1)(x^2-2x+1)\leq 0 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (x^2-2x-1)(x-1)^2 \leq 0$$

$$\Leftrightarrow x^2-2x-1\leq 0$$

$$x \in [1-\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2] $$.

We are looking for the largest $\delta$ so that

$$ |x-0|\leq \delta \Rightarrow |x^2-2x|\leq 1$$

$$\Leftrightarrow |x| \leq \delta \Rightarrow x\in [1-\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2]$$

$$ \Rightarrow \max \delta = \sqrt2 -1$$

Now, perhaps the question meant "the largest of the 4 solutions".

As D is the only valid answer, it should be that one.